Finding the threshold of a Cubic Bézier Curve.
I'm looking for equations for the points of a Cubic Bézier Curve, such that the Curve's X-derivative is always non-negative, and the equations must include all types of Curves that follow this rule.
We will have four points in a Two-Dimensional Cartesian Coordinate Plane. Each point labeled A, B, C, and D.
And a Cubic Bézier Curve is drawn using Points A, B, C, and D in that order.
Here are the following conditions I've wrote:

Point A is fixed at (0, 0) and Point B is fixed at (1, 1)
Points B and C can move freely, but cannot create a Cubic Bezier Curve where its X-derivative goes negative at any moment.


What I have observed:
At first, I thought the equations would simply be:
$$0\le B_{x}\le1$$
$$0\le C_{x}\le1$$
Until I stumbled upon this curve.
In the image, Point $C$ is out of bounds with my old equations, but is still a valid Cubic Bézier Curve. (Has not been proven yet)
After a while, I figured that it was guaranteed that Value $B_{x}$ cannot go behind $A_{x}$, and $C_{x}$ cannot go further than $D_{x}$.
This is because if these conditions were broken, the Curve's X-derivative will become negative at the beginning and/or at the end.
My refined equations are now:
$$0\le B_{x}\le???$$
$$???\le C_{x}\le1$$
I have left parts of the equations as question marks as I recently have no clue on what they're meant to be.
Now on this curve, the Values $B_{x}$ and $C_{x}$ are far enough that the Curve's X-derivative is going negative in the middle, and concluded that the distances between those two points must not exceed the distance from Value $A_{x}$ and Value $D_{x}$ (equal to $1$)
The additional equation I have added is:
$$\left|C_{x}-B_{x}\right|\le1$$

Here's a helpful Desmos Graph that contains Cubic Bézier Curves: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cnwooyfbst

This is the text of your homework. Nothing from you. Have you been working at least a little on it ?

@JeanMarie Yes I have tried working out how to solve it. This is not a real question on any Maths test (as far as I know.) I just convert my problems into questions you'd likely see in an exam test. Although, if you'd like, I could add a disclaimer on the post documenting what I just said in this comment.

OK. I don't need a disclaimer. But, is it necessary to "convert your problems into questions you'd likely see in an exam test" ? (inducing a mis-understanding by people reading your text). Instead, say in a direct way "I was asking myself if it is possible that ...."

When you say “x-derivative”, you mean $dy/dx$, right? Write down the equation of a Bézier curve with A and B fixed as you describe. Differentiate it to get $dy/dx$, and then see what the condition $dy/dx \ge 0$ tells you about points C and D. Show us what you did.
